# What is the fastest way to determine if any three numbers in an array sum to a specific value?

Tags: arrays, sorting, time, hash, sum

A number will only be used 2 or 3 times if it appears

I need the algorithm to pass a few unit tests.

These two Hashing and Sorting solutions both fail the large array duration test.

Hashing:

```
 public bool SumOfThree(int[] values, int sum, out int v1, out int v2, out int v3)
        {
            v1 = 0;
            v2 = 0;
            v3 = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length - 2; i++)
            {
                HashSet<int> s = new HashSet<int>();
                int curr_sum = sum - values[i];

                for (int j = i + 1; j < values.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (s.Contains(curr_sum - values[j]))
                    {
                        v1 = values[i];
                        v2 = curr_sum - values[j];
                        v3 = values[j];
                        return true;
                    }
                    s.Add(values[j]);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Sorting:

```
 public bool SumOfThree(int[] values, int sum, out int v1, out int v2, out int v3)
        {
            v1 = 0;
            v2 = 0;
            v3 = 0;
            Array.Sort(values);

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                int l = i + 1;
                int r = values.Length - 1;
                int x = values[i];
                while (l < r)
                {
                    if (x + values[l] + values[r] == sum)
                    {
                        v1 = x;
                        v2 = values[l];
                        v3 = values[r];
                        return true;
                    }

                    else if (x + values[l] + values[r] < sum) l++;

                    else r--;
                }
            }
            return false;
}
```

If you can spot anything wrong with these two solutions(performance wise) or know of any faster ones, I would appreciate it.

I also read some stuff about using binary search on a sorted array but haven't successfully implemented it.

The large array looks like this (the needed sum being 5+6+7=18)

```
                List<int> list = new List<int>();
                for (int i = -600000; i <= -500000; ++i)
                {
                    list.Add(i);
                }
                for (int i = 100000; i <= 200000; ++i)
                {
                    list.Add(i);
                }
                list.Add(5);
                list.Add(6);
                list.Add(7);
                Randomize<int>(list);
                array = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: What have you done to debug them?  In an IDE you could watch for and break on [i] == 5 then step through the code, or you could add logging output.  For easier debugging you could reduce the number of junk values to 5 negative, 5 positive.

Comment: They both work, just not fast enough

Comment: Ah, you asked `If you can spot anything wrong with these two solutions` which sounded like a bug problem not a performance issue.  One thing to consider is that for the sorted version you can stop  when `values[i] > sum/3`.

Comment: Still not fast enough even with this modification